# mvn plugin checkstyle fails with an unexpected token error

Tags: java, maven

Basically, I want to check my application with the goal `mvn checkstyle:check`. The version of the plugin is `maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.1.1`. However, executing the goal I get the following error message.

```
Failed during checkstyle configuration: 
Exception was thrown while processing .../SomeClass.java: 
IllegalStateException occurred while parsing file .../SomeClass.java. 
.../SomeClass.java:35:28: unexpected token: sa ->
```

The unexpected token is actually a simple Lambda expression.

```
someStream.map(sa -> { // This line here contains the unexpected token: sa -> ???  
                    // some mapping
                    return amount;
                })
                .reduce(Amount.ZERO_AMOUNT, MonetaryAmount::add);
```

I can't imagine that the plugin is not able to interpret java 8 syntax, but I can't find any further evidence of a wrong configuration.

Snippet from the effective pom

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>checkstyle</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
              <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
              <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
          <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
          <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

What have I missed?

**[UPDATE]**

The solution is to adjust the version of the [checkstyle](https://checkstyle.org/) library. If you look at the [default version defined insight the plugin, it is set to 8.29](https://github.com/apache/maven-checkstyle-plugin/blob/maven-checkstyle-plugin-3.1.1/pom.xml). I have set the plugin accordingly, as described in [Upgrading Checkstyle at Runtime](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html), to the [latest version, which is 9.1](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.puppycrawl.tools/checkstyle/9.1/jar). I have also defined the [latest checkstyle configuration for 'Google Java Style'](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) and the latest plugin version 3.1.2.

Why the plugin did not work with version 8.29 is still a mystery to me. The mentioned version was released in the first quarter of 2020 and lambda expressions should not be a problem.

Comment: Please run the maven command with the -X option and redirect the output to a file. The file may possibly contain the culprit

Comment: Sure. The following link shows the entire output: https://pastebin.com/RuH2FeJ1

Comment: Please check lines 350, 351 (and 455 too) of your output file: The following lines are of specific interest:

Checkstyle configuration: Exception was thrown while processing .../SomeClass.java: IllegalStateException occurred while parsing file .../SomeClass.java. .../SomeClass.java:35:28: unexpected token: sa -> [Help 1]

Comment: As already shown in the example above, here is the link that shows the area with the unexpected token: https://pastebin.com/3yGHYrGP

Comment: The question is where the `amount` in the `map(...)` is coming from...because it is either an instance variable (which could not work because it. has to be final) the `amount` has to be method coming from the type `T` or the example does not show the real code...

Comment: I've had the exact same problem on perfectly compilable code. Just upgrading the checkstyle version was sufficient for me.